# Search index tool for personal knowledge base files

Tags: search, information-retrieval

I have a large number of basic text, rtf, html, pdf and chm files that I store on a USB key as a personal knowledge base.

Up until now, to retrieve information, I've used a standard file searching tools (windows search,grep etc).  However these days a brute force search can take minutes due to sheer data size.  Also PDF and CHM are also more difficult to search.

Therefore I'm looking for a text indexing tool that will work well in this situation.  I want to avoid a dependency on an RDBMS (ie SQL Server, MySQL) as I would be using it on many different computers and do not want installation hassles.  A portable tool would be ideal.  On some machines I will also often be without internet access.

Something that provides a simple GUI allowing query input and quick access to results would be great.

I've thought about writing this myself, however it's a bit more work then I have time for right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Desktop](http://desktop.google.com/) does this indexing for you, as does the [Windows Desktop Search](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/default.mspx) (in Windows).  [Beagle](http://beagle-project.org/Main_Page) is a great Linux search tool.

Comment: I've used Google Desktop in the past and it wan't portable last time I looked.  But I'll have another look.  Never used Windows Desktop Search, I'll need to investigate more.  Thanks.

Comment: Re Google Desktop, watch out for Google Updater "malware".  You get this with most Google Apps whether you want it or not and it almost continually tries to access the internet.  Google also make it less then simple to remove.  Very dodgy in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you fancy a bit of a tinker, I'd use Lucene - either the pure java version or grab a copy of https://lucene.apache.org/.
This is a full text indexer and search library , would be perfect for running off the usb.